# How to serve www subdomain with VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: html, apache, http, mod-rewrite

I have directories for every website i serve like this: htdocs/domains/domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com

I use VirtualDocumentRoot to map the HOST NAME to the directory but it only works when the use browses to domain1.com and not to www.domain1.com

This is my directive:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\domains\%0\public_html
```

What do I do?

Thanks!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/499814/mod-vhost-alias-virtualdocumentroot-many-domains

Answer (score 0):

you have directory

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\domains\yourdomain\public_html
```

create shoutcut / softlink  `C:\xampp\htdocs\domains\www.yourdomain\public_html` and point it to `C:\xampp\htdocs\domains\yourdomain\public_html`

Under linux softlink can be create by `ln` command

```
ln -s /webroot/domains/yourdomain/public_html /webroot/domains/www.yourdomain/public_html
```